# How to instantiate a nested class given an instance of the containing class

Tags: c++, types, instance, nested-class

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    class NestedClass
    {
    };
};

BaseClass foo;
foo.NestedClass bar;
```

How to get the type from the instance?

Comment: What do you mean by: `I would like it to work with multiple classes containing the same nested class name`

Comment: For example if I have BaseClass2 which contains NestedClass

Comment: The question is obfuscating and not showing the real intend (design goal)

Comment: Yes, the question is not clear

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not english, but what I was looking for is in my answer.

Comment: Our question is: Why do you want to do that? Whatever normal thing you want to accomplish, there should be an idiomatic C++ way to do it.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you're trying to simply access the NestedClass *type* without scoping, or if you're trying to create new *instances* of NestedClass without scoping.

Comment: It was just to avoid typing `BaseClass` and get NestedClass just from the instance `foo`. Just a little wonder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is the following:

```
BaseClass::NestedClass bar;
```

You cannot avoid using the scope resolution operator, but you can make a `typedef` as a shorthand in the appropriate scope:

```
typedef BaseCLass::NestedClass NestedClass;
```

EDIT:
Based on the change in question, if you would like the type from an instance, in c++11 you can use `decltype`:

```
decltype(foo)::NestedClass;
```

but this is pointless as `decltype` would return BaseClass in this instance.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another way to do it ?

Comment: Fairly certain. Why don't you want the scope resolution or typedef?

Comment: Just because it works in C# and I was wondering if it would be possible in C++.

Comment: Maybe a little pointless, but just if I change the type of foo, it will still be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You use the scope resolution operator along with the base class name:

```
BaseClass::NestedClass bar;
```